# Javascript comparing two array of objects and remove the elements from first array based on second array and remove first occurence records

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have to remove the elements from arrayOne which is exists in arrayTwo, but I have to remove those records which is matched at first occurrences only. Remaining records should present ass it is if still they matched.

```js
let arrayOne = [
    {variantnames: 'Testing', variantvalues: '20', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
    {variantnames: 'free suger', variantvalues: '10', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
    {variantnames: 'chocolate', variantvalues: '15', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
    {variantnames: 'chocolate', variantvalues: '15', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
    {variantnames: 'Testing', variantvalues: '20', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
    {variantnames: 'free suger', variantvalues: '10', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
];

let arrayTwo = [
    {variantnames: 'Testing', variantvalues: '20', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
    {variantnames: 'free suger', variantvalues: '10', forDate: '2022-09-29'}
];


let result = arrayOne.filter(o1 => !arrayTwo.some(o2 => o1.variantnames == o2.variantnames));
console.log("result", result);
```

I know, we shold have to use findIndex to remove matched records from arrayOne but not able to get result.

Expected output should be

```
 result = [
     {variantnames: 'chocolate', variantvalues: '15', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
     {variantnames: 'chocolate', variantvalues: '15', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
     {variantnames: 'Testing', variantvalues: '20', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
     {variantnames: 'free suger', variantvalues: '10', forDate: '2022-09-29'},
 ];
```

Comment: Each entry in the `arrayTwo` has two entries in `arrayOne` with the same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `variantnames` from `arrayTwo`, and then within your `.filter()` method, [`.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete) the `variantnames` from that set for each object in `arrayOne`. The `.delete()` method on a Set will return `true` if it deletes an item from the set, and `false` if otherwise. If you come across the same `variantnames` property again, it won't be in the set, so it can't be deleted and so the object will be kept:

```js
const arrayOne = [ {variantnames: 'Testing', variantvalues: '20', forDate: '2022-09-29'}, {variantnames: 'free suger', variantvalues: '10', forDate: '2022-09-29'}, {variantnames: 'chocolate', variantvalues: '15', forDate: '2022-09-29'}, {variantnames: 'chocolate', variantvalues: '15', forDate: '2022-09-29'}, {variantnames: 'Testing', variantvalues: '20', forDate: '2022-09-29'}, {variantnames: 'free suger', variantvalues: '10', forDate: '2022-09-29'}, ];
const arrayTwo = [ {variantnames: 'Testing', variantvalues: '20', forDate: '2022-09-29'}, {variantnames: 'free suger', variantvalues: '10', forDate: '2022-09-29'} ];

const variants = new Set(arrayTwo.map(({variantnames}) => variantnames));
const result = arrayOne.filter(o1 => !variants.delete(o1.variantnames));
console.log("result", result);
```